# using SFTP: Permission denied, please try again,

Tags: sftp, troubleshooting

**System info**

```
uzair@zaidi:~/Desktop/tftpboot$ uname -a
Linux zaidi 3.11.0-20-generic #35~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 21:35:48 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
uzair@zaidi:~/Desktop/tftpboot$
```

**I get this error when using sftp:**

```
#sftp zaidi@192.168.1.9 
zaidi@192.168.1.9's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
zaidi@192.168.1.9's password:
```

even if enter correct password(of root)

Comment: What does `auth.log` say?

Comment: It might be a typo in the title of your question, but you do realize that sftp is not a tftp client? They're different protocols.

Comment: Wait, what?  `sftp` is for `ssh`, not `tftp`.  You're using the wrong client.

Answer (score 1):

[FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol), [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) and [TFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol) are different protocols (as is the lesser-used [FTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS), not to mention FTP over SSH). `sftp` is a client for the SFTP protocol, which operates over [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell). Evidently, you aren't authenticating correctly to the SSH server on 192.168.1.9, presumably because you're using TFTP credentials.

To use the TFTP protocol, use the `tftp` command. A TFPT server must be running. TFTP has no authentication, just specify the host name or IP address.

If you did mean to use SSH, make sure to enter the correct password — of the `zaidi` user, not of root, since you're specifying `zaidi` for the user name.